# Instagram API, AFNetworking 2.0 iOS client 400 error

Tags: ios, instagram, afnetworking-2

I haven't changed anything in my app and my code seems to generate the proper URL with access token attached, but I am getting a 400 error bad request for the past day. It doesn't seem as if Instagram has changed the endpoint. Can someone help me decipher the error log to see if there is any usable info here to help me debug? Access Token x'd out.

```
    Failure Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Request failed: bad request (400)" 
UserInfo=0x9261450 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/search?lat=37.785834&lng=-122.406417&distance=50&access_token=XXXX, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x92627d0> { URL: https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/search?lat=37.785834&lng=-122.406417&distance=50&access_token=XXXX } 
{ status code: 400, headers {
            "Cache-Control" = "private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
            Connection = "keep-alive";
            "Content-Language" = en;
            "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            Date = "Tue, 26 Aug 2014 05:19:53 GMT";
            Expires = "Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT";
            Pragma = "no-cache";
            Server = nginx;
            "Set-Cookie" = "csrftoken=26b1980509fc8303e630689c2d483074; expires=Tue, 25-Aug-2015 05:19:53 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/, ccode=US; Path=/";
            "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
            Vary = "Cookie, Accept-Language";
            "X-Ratelimit-Limit" = 5000;
            "X-Ratelimit-Remaining" = 4999;
        } }, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: bad request (400)}
```

Comment: Any idea on how to resolve the issue? I noticed that the problem occurs only on iOS 8. When the app runs on the iOS 7 device server communication works flawlessly.

Comment: @Michael In the above case it was Instagram's API that was down. Are you running in simulator? Everyone has been having trouble with the new simulator with regards to Core Location not calling didUpdateLocations. Check your logs to see if it's the API or a Core Location issue.